# find out: In how many word a character is present in a given Sentence: PYTHON

Tags: python, string

Before explaining my requirement, let me explain what I don't want:

```
s= 'Hello satya, have you achieved your goal'
s.count('l') #o/p: 3
#I don't want 3 instead  I need 2. How? explained below.
```

Expected Output:

```
{'H':3, 'e':3, 'l':2, 'o':4, 's':1, 'a':3....etc}
```

That is : take all unique letters/characters from that sentence.
Then find "in how many words that character is present" , so count that no of occurence and store in dictionary.

For example character 'l' is present 3 times in that sentence, but  present in 2 WORDS(in hello it is repeated but I want it to be counted as 1).

Please suggest. If i missed something to make my problem more understandable, please highlight.

Here is what I tried:

```
def char_word(s):
    s_d = {}
    chars = list(s.replace(' ', ''))
    print(chars)
    for char in chars:
        c_count = 0
        for word in s.split():
            if char in word:
                c_count += 1
            s_d[char] = c_count
    print(s_d)
    return s_d
```

Comment: As usual, what have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: posted my trial in question. Don't know if it is pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, split the string into individual words and create the output dictionary. I recommend using the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) c.ass, which is just a `dict` subclass designed to count occurrences:

```
import collections
counter = collections.Counter()
words = s.split()
```

Now loop through all of the words and create a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) from each word. Since `set` can't have duplicate values, it's guaranteed to have exactly one copy of each characters:

```
for word in words:
    characters = set(word)
```

And finally, loop through the now unique characters of the word, incrementing the counter's value for that character:

```
    for character in characters:
        counter[character] += 1
```

Also, you can shorten this quite a lot, even down to a one-liner:

```
>>> counter = collections.Counter(c for word in s.split() for c in set(word))
```

To get the count of a particular character, just access it through `counter[c]`:

```
>>> counter['l']
2
>>> counter['x']
0
>>> counter['H']
1
```

Comment: @Markus-did the One liner Worked for you, because I am getting "NameError: name 'word' is not defined"

Comment: @Satya Fixed. I accidentally pasted in an earlier prototype.

Comment: @markus-I prefer char_dict = dict(counter). Thanks for the OneLiner. Worked for me.Accepted as Answer.

Comment: @Satya They should work exactly the same except `Counter` returns `0` if a key doesn't exist, while `dict` raises a `KeyError`. But you're free to do as you please, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
sum(['l' in i for i in s.split()])
```

`s.split()` splits your sentence into words (it splits by ). Then the for-loop checks if the character `l` is in that particular word, yielding `True` or `False` if it is or is not. The `sum` function counts all the `True`s

Comment: This doesn't yield the desired output dictionary though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, too, within `groupby` from `itertools` module and `dict comprenesion` like this way:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = 'Hello satya, have you achieved your goal'
a = a.replace(',','').split()
sub = [j.lower() for k in a for j in set(k)]
final = {k:len(list(v)) for k,v in groupby(sorted(sub), lambda x: x)}
print(final)
```

Outut:

```
{'h': 3, 'u': 2, 's': 1, 'i': 1, 'c': 1, 'a': 4, 'd': 1, 'e': 3, 't': 1, 'v': 2, 'l': 2, 'o': 4, 'r': 1, 'g': 1, 'y': 3}
```